# Viewing JSON output in a simple WCF rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, json

How do I access this WCF function through the browser and view the JSON code...

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetData(int value);
```

Here's the code in my service...its just a sample function...

```
  public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
```

I tried pasting this url "http://localhost:25521/Service1.svc/GetData/1" on my browser but,it doesn't seem to execute the function.How do I execute this and test it on the browser to see the JSON stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Simply create a request to your URI with the "Request Builder", and make sure to add the header:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

You will get back the raw JSON.

Comment: I agree with using Fiddler. One additional point is that you also make sure to choose POST as the method (vs. GET).

Comment: I also had to use WebScriptServiceHostFactory to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

After catching the JSON, You can visually see it in this tool : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
not really related to your Q but its a really nice tool, chk it out